# Reading a certain position in a binary file using structs with pointers

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I am storing in a binary file a struct like this:

```
typedef struct user {
    char nick[6];
    int n_following;
    following *following;
}user;
```

That holds an array of structs of this type:

```
typedef struct following{
    char nick[6];
    int last_message;
}following;
```

I want to create and store in a binary file various users, and each time i do that i store their position in the file in a hashtable for later being able to seek them using fseek(), here is the aspect of an item in the hashtable:

```
typedef struct user_pos {
    char nick[6];
    int position_in_file;
}user_pos;
```

i tried to implement the ideia above and create two users and later try to fetch them, but i can only get one, since the other breaks the program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct following{
    char nick[6];
    int last_message;
}following;

typedef struct user {
    char nick[6];
    int n_following;
    following *following;
}user;    

void insert_user(char *input_a, int n){

    FILE *p;
    p=fopen("users","ab");
    user *new_user = malloc(sizeof(user));
    strcpy(new_user->nick, input_a);
    new_user->n_following = n;
    new_user->following = malloc(sizeof(following) * new_user->n_following);
    strcpy(new_user->following[0].nick, "la");
    new_user->following[0].last_message = 0;
    strcpy(new_user->following[1].nick, "zz");
    new_user->following[1].last_message = 2;

    fwrite(&new_user->nick, sizeof(new_user->nick), 1, p);
    fwrite(&new_user->n_following, sizeof(new_user->n_following), 1, p);
    fwrite(new_user->following, sizeof(following), new_user->n_following, p);
    printf("user created\n");
    fclose(p);
}

void get_user_info(char *input_a, int pos){


    FILE *p;
    p=fopen("users","rb");
    user *print_user = malloc(sizeof(user));

    fseek(p, pos* sizeof(user), SEEK_SET);

    fread(&print_user->nick, sizeof(print_user->nick), 1, p);
    fread(&print_user->n_following, sizeof(print_user->n_following), 1, p);
    print_user->following = malloc(sizeof(following));
    fread(print_user->following, sizeof(following), 2, p);

    printf("nick: %s, following: %d\n", print_user->nick, print_user->n_following);
    for(int i = 0; i < print_user->n_following; i++){
        printf("nick: %s, last_read: %d\n", print_user->following[i].nick, print_user->following[i].last_message);
    }

    fclose(p);
}

int main(){
    //hashtable *active_users = create();
    char buffer[38];
    char tipo;
    int n;
    char input_a[6];
    while(fgets(buffer, 38, stdin)){
        sscanf(buffer, "%c %s %d", &tipo, input_a, &n);
        switch(tipo) {
            case 'U' :
                insert_user(input_a, n);
                break;
            case 'S' :
                get_user_info(input_a, n);
                break;
            case 'X' :
                exit(0);
            default :
                printf("Operacao invalida\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the program fails with this kind of input:

```
input: U me 2
output: user created
input: U ro 2
output: user created
input: S me 0
output: nick: me, following: 2
        nick: la, last_read: 0
        nick: zz, last_read: 2
input: S ro 1//program breaks
```

Why is the program above finding one of the users and not the other?

Note: i know this would be better to do with normal .txt files but i want to use the speed of the fseek() function to get the users in the file

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve it to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Read also the hints I gave [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (second half of my answer)

Comment: Also, provide some [MCVE] in your question. In its current form, it is not one. So **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i really dont understand how does the question not fit the MCVE parameters, i provided a small part of the code where the error happens, and the input that causes it.

Comment: I cannot compile and run your code on my computer. That is what [MCVE] should be (including some input as an example)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, well would you want me to provide the full hashtable implementation? it´s the only thing that doesnt run

Comment: Without an [MCVE] (compilable and runnable on the computers of your readers) your question will soon be closed.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ok, i replaced the hashtable part, with an input from the user, now you can run it, but you have to give the position where the user is stored

Comment: @melpomene i dont get that error when i compile the program

Comment: `prog.c:9:5: error: unknown type name ‘user’`

Comment: @melpomene are you including the structs when running the program?

Comment: No. I'm using the main code block from your question.

Comment: @melpomene the structs are part of the program, they are not just part of the "main block of code" because i wanted to explain them, i tought that was pretty obvious

Comment: Then where do I put them? Am I supposed to just guess where each part goes?

Comment: @melpomene i update it now, should run now

Comment: `prog.c:60:17: error: ‘INPUTSIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: @melpomene check now... i dont know what you are trying to achieve with all those comments

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve by stubbornly refusing to create a [mcve]. But OK, I'll go away.

Comment: @melpomene i didnt refuse to that, very much on the contrary, everything you pointed out was easily replacable and not the related to the question, but the code is now ready to copy&paste to run

Comment: @MiguelD When you post an MCVE, people can copy/paste/compile is less than a minute. And in many cases, the compiler will generate a bunch of warnings, which tell you exactly what the problem is. So it's much more efficient for everyone if you post the MCVE in the first version of the question. In your case, the compiler is not generating any warnings. So good job on that. I'll take a deeper look. My guess is that this has something to do with the `following` pointer. Storing a pointer in a file doesn't work.

Comment: @user3386109 i understnd that i only posted the funtions i tought relavant in the begging to get to the point, its fixed now. i dont know if the problem is also when calculating the offset since there isnt much information online relative to structs with pointers in binary files so i might have made a mistake there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `fseek(p, pos* sizeof(user), SEEK_SET);` to skip to `pos` user in your file. `sizeof(user)` returns size in bytes of `user` struct but you have pointer `following` in this struct, which points to array filled by your `following` objects. If you want to skip to `pos` user you should have information how many following objects are in each user. You don't have this information so you can read your file user one by one to reach `pos` user.

```
// pseudocode 
get_user_info (int pos) {
   while (pos--) {
      skip 6 bytes // nick
      read 4 bytes n_following;
      skip n_following * sizeof(following) bytes
   }
   // here you can read data of pos user
}
```

Comment: so if i know how many users i have and how many following each one has i can then use fseek() to jump to the desired position in the file?

Comment: if *n-th* user has `Nfollowing` items, you can use this formula to get offset value `(6 + sizeof(int) + Nfollowing * sizeof(following))` to skip this user in file. If you have N-users to be skipped you need to add all these offsets and then call fseek once.

Comment: thank you that formula really works, and i do have those informations required

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems in the `get_user_info` function.

1. The offset calculation doesn't include the `following` structures. The file contains a `user` structure with some number of `following` structures, and then the next `user` structure. So there's no way to compute the offset without reading every user structure to get the `n_following` member.
2. The code only `malloc`s space for one `following` struct, but then reads 2 structures into that memory. The amount of memory should be `sizeof(following) * print_user->n_following`
3. The `fread` is using a hard-code 2 instead of `n_following` when reading the following structures.